# Android - how to check which calendar event is currently in progress?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I would like to check in internal Android calendar for event which is currently in progress (started before current time, and ends after current time). I'm using Android 2.2

I was playing around with this piece of code - I was trying to set start time to `now` but this doesn't work, it returns events that started after this moment.

```
//building query uri
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
long now = new Date().getTime();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 80);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 80);

Log.d("AlarmReciever", "querying for calendar with id:" + calendarId);
//interating over events
Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(), new String[] { "title" }, "Calendars._id=" + calendarId, null, null);
while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
    final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
    Toast.makeText(context, "title: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could show me how to do this correctly. Thanks!